# Array values from array_intersect

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the array intersect function.
The first array is generated by the post method:

```
$em_arr = json_decode(str_replace('\\', '', ($_GET["em_arr"])));
```

The second array is from mysql query:

```
$new=array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ms_status = '1'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($k = @mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$new[$k['hash']]=$k['ms_email'];    
}
```

Then I compare these two arrays using :

```
$same=array_intersect($new,$em_arr);
```

The result is:

```
Array ( [956c0edcb9b93e05130e472f00b65b334dee786f] => test@test.com [555c0edcb9b93e05130e472f00b65b334dee786f] => test2@test2.com )
```

Is it possible to, as a result of this array_intersect function, beside email address and hash get  other data from mysql query (like "id", "name") or I need to run another mysql query and select users with email addresses get as result of array_intersect?

Comment: Please post a sample of your two input arrays, it's unclear what data exactly you're working with.

Comment: I think you may be going about this in the wrong way: rather than fetching a large set of data from the DB and then filtering it in PHP, you should be building an appropriate WHERE clause, and letting MySQL efficiently filter the data for you.